# An equivalence in topological spaces

Tags: general-topology

I have to prove this:

Let $(X,T)$ be a topological space , then it is equivalent:

$1)$  The closure of an open set is an open set.

$2)$  If $U$ and $V$ are disjoint open sets, their closures are also disjoint.

I proved $ 1\Rightarrow 2$, but I see no way of doing the other one. Any help would be helful with this.

Answer (score 1):

We can just use the definition of closure here. Note that the closure of open set $U$ is the complement of the union of all disjoint open sets $V_i$. We know by $2$ that the closure of $V$ is disjoint with the closure of $U$, which means $\overline{V_i}\in\bigcup V_i$ for all $V_i$.

We want to show that $\bigcup V_i=\bigcup\overline{V_i}$ is closed. We know that $\bigcup\overline{V_i}\subset\overline{\bigcup{V_i}}$, so we simply need to show the $\supset$ relation between these two sets. Can you finish from here?

Comment: I don't understand why 2 implies that $\overline{V_i}\in\bigcup V_i $. And also why you want to show that $\bigcup V_i=\bigcup\overline{V_i}$ is a closed set.